# Compare right-unbounded time intervals with joda-lib

Tags: java, jodatime

Is it possible to determine wether two rigth-unbounded intervals (intervals with one boundary at infinity) overlap or not?

I've tried this (and other similar variations):

```
Instant now = new Instant(new Date().getTime());
Interval i2 = new Interval(now, (ReadableInstant) null);
Interval i1 = new Interval(now, (ReadableInstant) null);
boolean overlapping = i2.overlaps(i1);
```

But according to the docs, using `null` as a second parameter means "now" instead of "infinity".

**EDIT**: I've found [this answer](http://joda-interest.219941.n2.nabble.com/unbounded-intervals-tp4839992p4851375.html) in the mailing list, so it seems to be impossible with  Joda. I am now looking for alternative implementations.

Comment: `<nitpick>`A **[half-open interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-open_interval#Terminology)** is not the same thing as "interval with one boundary at infinity." `</nitpick>`

Comment: I've edited the question with @Matt comments

Answer (score 4):

If both intervals start at `t = -∞` , or if both intervals end at `t = +∞`, they will **always** overlap, regardless of the start date.

If interval `A` starts at `t = -∞` and interval `B` ends at `t = +∞`, they overlap **iff**
`A.start > B.start`.

Answer (score 2):

Hacky solution:

```
/**
 * Checks if two (optionally) unbounded intervals overlap each other.
 * @param aBeginn
 * @param aEnde
 * @param bBeginn
 * @param bEnde
 * @return
 */
public boolean checkIfOverlap(LocalDate aBeginn,LocalDate aEnde, LocalDate bBeginn,LocalDate bEnde){
    if(aBeginn == null){
        //set the date to the past if null
        aBeginn = LocalDate.now().minusYears(300);
    }
    if(aEnde == null){
        aEnde = LocalDate.now().plusYears(300);
    }
    if(bBeginn == null){
        bBeginn = LocalDate.now().minusYears(300);
    }
    if(bEnde == null){
        bEnde = LocalDate.now().plusYears(300);
    }

    if(aBeginn != null && aEnde != null && bBeginn != null && bEnde != null){
        Interval intervalA = new Interval(aBeginn.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(),aEnde.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay());
        Interval intervalB = new Interval(bBeginn.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(),bEnde.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay());
        if(intervalA.overlaps(intervalB)){
            return true;
        }
    } else{
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Instead of now +/- 300 years, this minimum date can be used: `new LocalDate(-292_275_054, 1, 1);` (year -292,275,054 B.C.) and this maximum date can be used `new LocalDate(292_278_993, 12, 31)`(year 292,278,993 A.D.). These limits are defined in [joda-time GregorianChronology class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.7/org/joda/time/chrono/GregorianChronology.java#GregorianChronology.0MIN_YEAR).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a `Range<DateTime>` ([from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html)), which should provide all the construction options and comparison functions you need.

```
Range<DateTime> r1= Range.atLeast(DateTime.now());
Range<DateTime> r2 = Range.atLeast(DateTime.now());
boolean overlap = r1.isConnected(r2) && !r1.intersection(r2).isEmpty();
```